# Could not find or load main class App when creating the jar file for javafx application

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, jar

I am creating the jar file for the application using intelliJ artifact building. In here I keep getting this error even though I have configured all the options as mentioned in the documentation. In output layout I have configured the Main class, MANIFEST.MF file. And I have tried running the file using the terminal in Linux.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I added the Java EE-6 library to the output layout of the project in intelliJ IDE which includes the javafx executables. Finally it is executable through the command line using the Java launcher.